# How to allign brackets with the text?

Tags: vertical-alignment

I want to write Z[x] with those brackets alligned with the Z. I've tried using `\lbrack` and `\rbrack` but the result is basically the same, so what's the best way to force it to stay on the same line?

Comment: Could you please add a [minimal but complete document](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) showing what you have tried? Literally using `Z[x]` will give you brackets on the same line as `Z`.

Comment: Please, explain how should be this bracket aligned in a case `$Z[y]$`? or `$Z[f]$`? Size of brackets and its alignment is depended on content in brackets. The same do `\left[` and `\right]`.

Comment: Okay, so basically what I'd like to get is to align the brackets according to Z, because by using [ ] or \lbrack \rbrack the brackets go a little bit under the Z and I want to avoid this.

Comment: The brackets used for (La)TeX are designed so that they do not change size if your expression is `$Z[y]$` or a subscript is involved.  "Text" brackets often are designed to not extend below the baseline, but that isn't appropriate for math.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SX! It seems to me this is a matter of font choice. That said, here is a way to align the “bottom” of brackets with the base line without changing fonts:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\raisedChar}[1]{%
  \setbox\z@=\hbox{#1}%
  \leavevmode
  \raise\dp\z@\box\z@
}

\newcommand*{\@TextOrMathOpening}[1]{%
  \TextOrMath{#1}{\mathopen{#1}}%
}

\newcommand*{\@TextOrMathClosing}[1]{%
  \TextOrMath{#1}{\mathclose{#1}}%
}

\newcommand*{\raisedOpeningBracket}{%
  \@TextOrMathOpening{\raisedChar{[}}%
}

\newcommand*{\raisedClosingBracket}{%
  \@TextOrMathClosing{\raisedChar{]}}%
}

\newlength{\widthOfOpeningBracket}
\newlength{\widthOfClosingBracket}
\newlength{\heightOfZ}
\settowidth{\widthOfOpeningBracket}{[}
\settowidth{\widthOfClosingBracket}{]}
\settoheight{\heightOfZ}{Z}

\newcommand*{\scaledAndRaisedOpeningBracket}{%
  \@TextOrMathOpening{%
    \resizebox{\widthOfOpeningBracket}{\heightOfZ}{\raisedChar{[}}%
  }%
}

\newcommand*{\scaledAndRaisedClosingBracket}{%
  \@TextOrMathClosing{%
    \resizebox{\widthOfClosingBracket}{\heightOfZ}{\raisedChar{]}}%
  }%
}
\makeatother

% Abbreviations
\let\OB\raisedOpeningBracket
\let\CB\raisedClosingBracket
\let\sOB\scaledAndRaisedOpeningBracket
\let\sCB\scaledAndRaisedClosingBracket

\begin{document}
Z[x]\quad $Z[x]$
\medskip

Z\OB x\CB\quad $Z\OB x \CB$
\medskip

Z\sOB x\sCB\quad $Z\sOB x \sCB$
\end{document}
```

[image: Screenshot]

It feels a bit hackish, though. I don't propose making `[` and `]` active characters, as that would break too many things, but you could choose a pair of Unicode characters and proceed with either `\newunicodechar` as in [this message](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/16007) or with `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter` as in [that message](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/490999/73317).

Comment: One can not deny that it looks terrible. Nice answer

Comment: That's actually a bit extreme but in someway it is what I need. I mean, the last two examples are close to what I asked, because you aligned the lower part of the brackets to the Z but to that, the upper part now is too high.  I guess that with the code you gave one could perfectly align the brackets accordingly to the dimension of the Z.

Comment: I've added macros that additionally scale the brackets in the vertical direction so that they have the same height as a Z. Please use the tick mark on the left if this answers your question. :-)